# Catch all block doesn't catch DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, directory, catch-all

I have received the support ticket that makes me (uncomfortably) numb.
The WPF application has the following code to remove temporary directory:

```
try
                {
                    Directory.Delete(dir, true);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // ignored
                }
```

The main window' dispatcher unhandled exception handler just shows the dialog box with the info on exception (including the stack). And here it is:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\6\86248143'.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath,
>   Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at the method calling
>   Directory.Delete

Can anybody point me out why the exception was not caught in the catch all block?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio ?

Comment: The problem in Release mode and happens only at customer site - the exception is not caught in the nearest catch block but propagated until UnhandledExceptionHandler is called - that how i see it from logs

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoO7s.png) CheckBox is not checked. It ignores the try catch blocks and "breaks when that exception type is thrown"
Note; I guess it was Visual Studio.

Comment: No, the problem is not in VS while debugging.  The problem in Release mode and happens only at customer site - the exception is not caught in the nearest catch block but propagated until UnhandledExceptionHandler is called